# Kodak scaner i1150 and s3000 series scaning issue on dell optiplex 7040 65w using 22.04

Tags: drivers, dell, scanner, kodak

I am using dell optiplex 7040 (snap attached)

I have installed the drivers of the scanner it installed successfully after adding multiarch support

after lsusb it shows scanner and after xsane started it shows failed to open device

[system information](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GviNT.png)

[scaner output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZUGb5.png)

[command output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vzUJ4.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Many device access problems are permission problems, and can be resolved through group membership changes.

You can find the device name by watching `sudo journalctl --follow` as you connect your device. OR `ls -1 -l /dev >dev.before`, connect the device, wait 10 seconds, `ls -1 -l /dev >dev.after;diff dev.{before,after}`.

Specifically, if `ls -l`  shows that the group permissions (the second "`rwx`" triplet) is "`rw`" (e.g."`-rw-rw----`"), then, adding oneself to the group that owns the device will grant `rw` access.

Here's how:

```
# change to your device name 
device="/dev/YourDevice"
sudo adduser $USER $(stat -c "%G" $device)
```

This allows you membership in the group that can `rw` the device, **but there is one more step.**

To make all your processes members of the new group, logout and login. Group memberships are set up at `login` time.

To create a single process in the new group (for testing, prior to logout/login):

```
newgrp $(stat -c "%G" $device)
```

or, just type the group name. See `man newgrp`.